# Excel If Statement finding number of days between two dates

Tags: excel, if-statement

As an example I have three columns Target completion,  Actual completion and Entered date

```
Column A Target Completion 1/5/13/2013
Column B Actual Completion 1/25/2013
Column C Entered Date 1/2/2013
```

I need to add 30 days to Column A (Target Completion) and then compare that new date to Column B (Actual Completion) and finally show the result in days.

Like this;

```
Column A Target Completion 1/5/13/2013
Column B Actual Completion 1/25/2013
Column C Entered Date 1/2/2013
```

Result = -10 days (30 days are added to column A then minus column B)

```
Column A Target Completion 3/1/13/2013
Column B Actual Completion 5/1/2013
Column C Entered Date 1/2/2013
```

Result = 30 days (30 days are added to column A then minus column B)

I have been trying to get this if statement to work …but no luck!! Thank you in advance.

```
=if(E14="",DATEDIF(DATEVALUE("06/28/2013"),TODAY(),"d"),DATEDIF(E14,C14,"d"))
```

Comment: have you try my answer ?

Comment: This also works =IF(B1>A1 +30,"Late","")

Comment: So, you've figured out the problem now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try EDATE() function

```
=Edate(A1,1)-B1
```

Reference .. http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/edate-function-HP010342465.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP010342402

Answer (score 0):

Excel stores dates as the number of days since Jan 1, 1900, so to get the number of days just subtract.  So to add 30 days to column A then subtract column B, in row 1 that would be:

```
=A1 + 30 - B1
```

The if statement would seem to be trying to do something like

```
=IF(E14="",TODAY() - DATE(2013,6,13),C14-E14))
```